# POST request is not tallied with the form in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in Laravel.

My problem is, when I tried to update my form, it kept saying that the tablename not found eventhough I already mentioned it inside my Model. But when I debugged, I found that the request is not the same from what I put inside my form.

[image: Here is what I got from the dump.]

But my form actually doesn't have that.

Any idea how this is happening, guys? Pretty sure I missed something but unsure what is it.

**Event Model**

```
class Event extends Model
{
//
protected $fillable = ['title', 'objective', 'date', 'venue', 'description', 'slug'];

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
}
```

**Event Controller**

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
  public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
{
   //
   $validated = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string|unique:event|min:5|max:100',
        'objective' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
        'date' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
        'venue' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
        'description' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000'
    ]);

    // Create slug from title
    $validated['slug'] = Str::slug($validated['title'], '-');

    // Update Post with validated data
    $event->update($validated);

    // Redirect the user to the created post woth an updated notification
    return redirect(route('events.edit', [$event->slug]))->with('notification', 'Event updated!');

}
```

**Edit Blade Page**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('events.update', [$event->slug]) }}">

                    @csrf
                    @method('patch')
                    @include('partials.errors')

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Title</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $event->title }}" class="input" placeholder="Title" minlength="5" maxlength="100" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Objective</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea name="content" class="textarea" placeholder="Content" minlength="5" maxlength="2000" required rows="10">{{ $event->objective }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Date</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $event->date }}" class="input" placeholder="Title" minlength="5" maxlength="100" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Venue</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $event->venue }}" class="input" placeholder="Title" minlength="5" maxlength="100" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Description</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea name="content" class="textarea" placeholder="Content" minlength="5" maxlength="2000" required rows="10">{{ $event->description }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <button type="submit" class="button is-link is-outlined">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `name` attribute of Date, Venue and Description and Objective.

Answer (score 0):

On your edit blade page, the input names are alternating 'title' and 'content'

can you rename the input names so that they can be unique